# FullCalendar | Dayrender for specific events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

Is it possible to modify full cell for an specific event adding for example an id in those events?:

Example dayrender for full calendar:

```
dayRender: function(date, cell) {
                    cell.css("background-color", "red");
                  },
```

Events

```
 events: [
                {
                id: 'magno',
                title: 'All Day Event',
                start: new Date(2019, 02, 1),
                },
                ]
```

Imagine that you want to apply dayRender for this specific event. At least doesn't seems related with this at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

Thanks.

Kind regards.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender gives you control over the appearance of each individual event

Answer (score 0):

When an event is rendered the cells are already rendered so unfortunately there is no access to the dayRender callback when an event is rendered.

To set the background color of a cell you could use background events, the docs explain how to set the color.

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/background-events